# Checking the number inside a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string, say

`var Str = 'My name is 123 and my name is 234'`.

Now I split this as

`var arrStr = Str.split(' ');`

I iterate through the array and have different logic depending upon whether the word is a string or number. How do i check that? I tried `typeof` which didn't work for me.

**EDIT:**

After Seeing multiple answers. Now, I am in despair, which is the most efficient way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you care only about the numbers, then instead of using split you can use a regular expression like this:

```
var input = "My name is 123 and my name is 234";
var results = input.match(/\d+/g)
```

If you care about all pieces, then you can use another expression to find all non-space characters like this:

```
var input = "My name is 123 and my name is 234";
var results = input.match(/\S+/g)
```

Then iterate them one by one, and check if a given string is a number or not using the famous [`isNumeric()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1830844/439667) function posted by @CMS in this [famous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18082/439667).

```
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

NOTE: Thanks to @Pointy and if you want them as numbers, `input.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)`.

Comment: ... and if you want them as numbers, `input.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)`

Comment: Gotta love how 4 people upvoted this before you corrected it. Prior to your edit the result of this was simpy `["d"]`. Good job on catching that yourself though.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly Yeah I noticed that, sometimes they just like the sound of it :)

Comment: @Sniffer : Some suggest unary + is faster than parseFloat() ?

Comment: @cipher Have you seen a benchmark about this, and by how much ? How much do you care for speed here. Anyway the `isNumberic()` method is taken from a famous question with a lot of discussions and opinions and the guys seem to be happy with it :).

Comment: If i can get to same solution using different methods. It's just: "why not the fastest ?". But since the question was discussed for long. Maybe there's  a reason. Anyways, thanks

Comment: @cipher You are correct, but that's a very well written and professional answer written bythe best, so don't hesitate :). Please don't forget to accept this answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to attempt to convert your array values to an integer.

To iterate them you can use a `for` loop:

```
for(i=0;i<arrStr.length;i++) {
    var result = !isNaN(+arrStr[i]) ? 'number' : 'string';
    console.log(result);
}
```

Here I'm using a unary `+` to attempt to convert the value of each array value to a number. If this fails, the result will be `NaN`. I'm then using JavaScript's `isNaN()` method to test if this value is `NaN`. If it isn't, then it's a number, otherwise it's a string.

The result of this using the string you've provided is:

```
string
string
string
number
string
string
string
string
number
```

To use this in an `if` statement, we can simply:

```
for(i=0;i<arrStr.length;i++) {
    if(isNaN(+arrStr[i])) {
        /* Process as a string... */
    }
    else {
        /* Process as a number... */
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/GW9qq/).

Comment: I think the unary + does evil?
`typeof +"string"` returns number

Comment: @cipher I fixed my answer, sorry about that!

Comment: I'm seeing you basically replaced `Number(arrStr[i])` to `+arrStr[i]` , Am I Correct?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#-_.28Unary_Plus.29

Answer (score 1):

To expound on Sniffer's answer...

```
var input = "My name is 123 and my name is 234";
var numberArray = input.match(/\d+/g);
var wordArray = input.match(/[A-Za-z]+/g);

for (var number in numberArray)
{
    //do something
}
for (var word in wordArray)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While researching, I found out about the `Number()` object. This is generally used to work with manipulation of numbers. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) has a good documentation .

I found out that `Number()` returns `NaN` (Not a Number) when not passed a number. Since no number returns NaN, It could be a good way to check whether the passed object is string or a number literal.

So my code would be:

```
if (Number(arrStr[i]) == NaN){
    //string
} else  {
    //number
}
```